# How to convert List<Object> flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm new in flutter and need to help:

I have already got

```
final List<Genres> genres = [{1,"comedy"}, {2,"drama"},{3,"horror"}]
```

from api.

```
class Genres {

  final int id;
  final String value;

  Genres({this.id,this.value});
}
```

In another method I get genres.id.(2) How can I convert it to genres.value ("drama")?

Comment: Hi! Please add more details of that you are trying to do. Also, whenever you add code, please use the formatting function so it's more readable

Comment: It's still not very clear what you are asking for. Try adding an example of what you would want the resulting data to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a `Genre` from an `id` is inconvenient when your data structure is a `List`. You have no choice but to iterate over the list and compare the `id` value to the `id` of each element in the list:

```dart
final id = 2;
final genre = genres.firstWhere((g) => g.id == id, orElse: () => null);
```

The problem with this code is that it's slow and there could be multiple matches (where the duplicates after the first found would be ignored).

A better approach would be to convert your list to a `Map` when you first create it. Afterwards, you can simply use an indexer to get a `Genre` for an ID quickly and safely.

```dart
final genresMap = Map.fromIterable(genres, (item) => item.id, (item) => item);

// later...

final id = 2;
final genre = genresMap[id];
```

This way, there is guaranteed to not be any duplicates, and if an ID doesn't exist then the indexer will simply return null.

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate over the json result of the api and map them to the Gener class like so,

```dart
void fn(id) {
  final gener = geners.firstWhere((gener) => gener['id'] == id);

  // now you have access to your gener
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I explained not very well. I corrected it

Comment: so u get the id in a method, and in that method you want to get the value of that gener? @sk784

Comment: can you vote/accept the answer @sk784, thanks, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can find the item inside the `List<Genres>` like this

```
Genres element = list.firstWhere((element) => element.id == 2); // 2 being the id you give in the question as an exaple. You should make it dynamic
print(element.value);
```